# Multiple elements in the array having the same value, will get a different percentile

Tags: php, arrays

I am calculating the number that falls into a specific percentile. However, the problem with my equation is that if multiple elements in the array having the same value, this code will assign a different percentile number to each of those elements.

```
$percentile_50 = $array[round((50/100) * $count_array -.5)];
```

For example, first column is the percentile, and second is the score. You can see that same second gets different percentile, but in fact it should be the same.

How can I avoid this?

```
5-1
10-1
15-1
20-1
25-2
30-2
35-3
40-4
45-4
50-5
55-6
60-7
65-9
70-11
75-14
80-17
85-23
90-32
95-53
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the kth percentile, you should :

1. Order all the values in the data set from smallest to largest.
2. Multiply k percent by the total number of values, n.

   - This number is called the index.
3. If the index obtained in Step 2 is not a whole number, round it up to the nearest whole number and go to Step 4. If the index obtained in Step 2 is a whole number, go to Step 5.
4. Count the values in your data set from left to right (from the smallest to the largest value) until you reach the number indicated by Step 3.
   The corresponding value in your data set is the kth percentile
5. Count the values in your data set from left to right until you reach the    number indicated by Step 2.
   The kth percentile is the average of that corresponding value in your data set and the value that directly follows it.

( from [here](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-calculate-percentiles-in-statistics/))

Translated to PHP:

```
$sData = sort($data);
$percentile = 50/100;
$index = ceil($percentile * count($sData));
$value = $sData[$index-1];
```

Or shorter:

```
$sData = sort($data);
$value = $sData[ceil((50/100) * count($sData)) - 1]
```

However, in a small dataset, sometimes the percentiles end up the same. For example, the following code produces the following output.

**Code**

```
$data = array(74, 15, 25, 62, 45,  9, 16, 63, 60, 76,  7, 20, 67, 30, 12);
sort($data);
for($i=5;$i<100;$i+=5){
    echo $i . " - " . $data[ceil(($i/100) * count($data)) - 1];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output**

```
5 - 7
10 - 9
15 - 12
20 - 12 //same as aboce
25 - 15
30 - 16
35 - 20
40 - 20 //same as above
45 - 25
50 - 30
55 - 45
60 - 45 //same as above
65 - 60
70 - 62
75 - 63
80 - 63 //same as above
85 - 67
90 - 74
95 - 76
```

Comment: thank you for this, however my output has no difference than yours , meaning that we both give different percentile to same numbers

Comment: yes, well that is how percentile works mathematically. You need something else that is unique for each number. Maybe a Z-Score? @Xalloumokkelos